# How to batch edit text in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

*Problem*: I have dozens of jupyter notebooks that all have some text that I need to replace.

**Example**

Each notebook contains a reference to an external file in directory `foo`.

```
 ./
  |- foo
  |   |- image.jpg
  |   |- ...
  |- notebooks
      |- file1.ipynb
      |- file2.ipynb
      |- file3.ipynb
      |- ...
```

However, the `foo` directory will soon be renamed to `bar`, thereby orphaning the associated links in the notebooks.  Thus, I will need to rename all the links in each notebook from the old **`foo`** directory name to the new **`bar`** name, e.g. `foo/image.jpg` to `bar/image.jpg`.

*Question*: Opening each one by one will take a lot of time.  Is there an efficient and safe solution for batch editing text for multiple jupyter notebooks?

**Approach**

Since notebooks are essentially json files, I am considering a simple search and replace in VSCode.  I've tried this on a test notebook and it seems to work, but I am not sure if this method will somehow corrupt the files.  I appreciate any safe suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on *nix? Then sed will work.

```
cd ./path/to/notebooks
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *.ipynb
```

or you can use vim `argsadd` coupled with `argsdo`

ie.,

```
vim
:cd path/to/notebooks
:arg *.ipynb
:argdo %s/foo/bar/ge | update
```

Comment: I'm using Windows and am unfamiliar with unix tools. Will this safely edit without corrupting my notebooks?

Comment: it will. windows 10 now supports linux subsystem. Btw, you should be keeping the files under version control.